# Updating postgreSQL column with EXTRACT function (More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

Using PostgreSQL 9.1 table, I want to update day column with  extracting day number from timestamp column.

```
table:

id|name|timesatmp
-----------------
```

I created a day column then tried to extract the day number following:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 16
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

When i tried to update table using:

```
UPDATE table SET day = 
( SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM "timestamp") FROM table);
```

I got this error:

```
More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I've found that i can repair my statement by adding `LIMIT 1` to the subquery to ensure that at most 1 row is returned. but still not sure if it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the need for this sub-select, just update the column:

```
UPDATE table SET day = EXTRACT (DAY FROM "timestamp");
```

The real question is though: why do you want to store information that can be derived from the existing data (and in this case: without any additional cost)

---

Btw: `timestamp` is a horribly name for a column. First because it's also the name of a datatype and thus is *really* confusing. Secondly (and more importantly I think) it doesn't document at all what the column contains. A "start date"? an "end date"? a "due date" a "valid date"? ...

Comment: Thank you! the thing is that i need to create a separate column in order to use it as portioning key in my clustered db. thanks for your advice about column name!

Comment: @Oxi: if you want that as a partitioning key, you probably should do this in a trigger.

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean? I have 2 nodes. when i insert the data i want it to get separated by day (insert day 1,3,5,7...etc in node 1 and day 2,4,6...etc in node 2) let's say i make the trigger on node 1 only insert (day 1,3,5... etc) where would the other days inserted in the node go?